# How to retrieve the text from an outer element using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to retrieve the text 'caught jake' from the below code using selenium webdriver?

Am able to point to that text using the below xpath but am unable to print the text. :(

//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/child::text()

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large 20 columns">
      <table class="batting-table innings" width="100%">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="tr-heading">
               <tr>
                  <tr class="dismissal-detail" style="display: table-row;">
                     <td width="2%" />
                     <td colspan="8">
                        <b>12.6</b> caught Jake
                        <b>73/4</b>
                        <br/>
```

Comment: Please give some more details. Which programming language do you use and what did you tried?

Comment: Am using 'JAVA'. Am able to get the text '12.6' and '73/4' but am not able to fetch the text 'caught Jake' using Xpath.

Comment: using b1 as part of the xpath am able to get 12.6 and b2 am able to get 73/4 but I don't know how to retrieve the text 'Caught Jake'

Comment: WebElement txt= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/child::text()"));
 
 System.out.println(txt);      unable to print the text how to convert the webelement to text.

Answer (score 0):

Using java you can retrieve from following lines:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='large 20 columns']")).getText();
System.Out.print("Text= "+text);
```

Above line will return all inner tags string's of div element.

If you want to get only 12.6 text, then use below lines:

```
  String text =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='batting-table innings']/tr/tr/tr/td[2]/b")).getText();
  System.Out.print("Text= "+text);
```

And be sure that there should be single element which has this xpath 'By.xpath("//table[@class='batting-table innings']/tr/tr/tr/td[2]/b")', otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: Am able to get the text '12.6' and '73/4' but am not able to fetch the text 'caught Jake' using Xpath.

Comment: using b1 as part of the xpath am able to get 12.6 and b2 am able to get 73/4 but I don't know how to retrieve the text 'Caught Jake'

Answer (score -1):

depend on your language, you can use following xpath expression:

```
//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table/tbody/tr/tr/td[2]/child::text()
```

full Java code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String jsx = "return  document.evaluate(\"//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/child::text()\", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;";

        String objList =  js.executeScript(jsx);
        System.out.println( (String) objList);
```

Comment: Am using 'JAVA'. Am able to get the text '12.6' and '73/4' but am not able to fetch the text 'caught Jake' using Xpath.
     
using b1 as part of the xpath am able to get 12.6 and b2 am able to get 73/4 but I don't know how to retrieve the text 'Caught Jake' alone.

Comment: This is not working showing exception in main thread unable to locate element error              //WebElement Text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table/tbody/tr/tr/td[2]/child::text()"));
  System.out.print("Text= "+ Text);

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table/tbody/tr/tr/td[2]/child::text()"}

Comment: WebElement Text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table/tbody/tr/tr/td[2]/child::text()")); 

System.out.print("Text= "+ Text);

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at Webtable_CaughtJack.main(Webtable_CaughtJack.java:24)

Comment: CODE USED //////////  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String jsx = "var iterator = document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table/tbody/tr/tr/td[2]/child::text()\", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null ); var arrayXpath = new Array();  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext(); while (thisNode) {arrayXpath.push(thisNode.textContent);  thisNode = iterator.iterateNext(); }    return arrayXpath;";

        String objList =  (String) js.executeScript(jsx);
        System.out.println(objList);

Comment: This xpath points to the text caught jack, used firepath to checkit. But am unable to convert the webelement to string and print it, help me with this.\\\\   WebElement txt= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/child::text()"));
 
 System.out.println(txt);

Comment: you will change xpath in document.evaluate function

Comment: Tried with your code am getting this error -->   Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String
2 fixes are available
Add cast to string, 
Change type of ‘objlist’ to object

Comment: Ok. Added (String)  casting. Try now

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: which java version do you use?

Comment: I installed same now, and it should working now. Please try now